# Plotting x interval values against y values using R

Tags: r, plot

I have some data as below. I can't use scatter plot for visualisation because I want to plot Age on the x-axis at intervals - 30-39;40-49;50-59, 60-69 etc. Perhaps a kind of bar plots.

```
Age score
60  0.56
30  0.02
70  0.92
50  0.45
45  0.31
69  0.75
62  0.54
32  0.30
52  0.50
```

I'm not sure what kind of plot will be good for what I want. Any ideas? Someone mentioned proportional plot, but I'm not sure how to do that in R. Thanks.

Comment: What intervals do you have in mind? In your data there is Age 30;32;45, so you want intervals 30-32 & 32-45?

Comment: I'm still exploring the data. We can try 30-32, 32-45.

Comment: What are you trying to show with the plot? Just report the scores? Represent the variability of the scores within an age interval? Show the mean scores within an age group?

Comment: What I want to do is represent the variability of the scores within an age interval

Comment: Seems like using `cut` to create an age factor and boxplot to present the data should work. Do some searching on those terms ... probably hundreds of examples will appear.

Comment: Thanks so much @42. I was able to carry out a boxplt like this:seqs <- seq(min(df$Age), max(df$Age), by=5)
boxplot(as.numeric(df$score) ~ seqs)

Comment: EDIT: to above comment: seqs <- seq(min(df$Age), max(df$Age), by=5)
L <- cut(as.numeric(Age), seqs)
boxplot(as.numeric(df$score) ~ L)

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question with tested code.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will put the Ages into bins. To show variability visually, I suggest a box plot and/or geom_point.

```
df <- data.frame(Age=c(60,30,70,50,45,69,62,32,52),
                 score=c(0.56,0.02,0.92,0.45,0.31,0.75,0.54,0.30,0.50))

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

binWidth <- 20
df2 <- df %>% mutate(bin = floor(Age/binWidth)*binWidth)


ggplot() + 
geom_boxplot(data=df2,aes(x=bin,y=score,group=bin),width=binWidth) + 
geom_point(data=df2,aes(x=bin,y=score))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jason for your help.